# Vue2/Typescript: is it possible to @Watch a module property?

Tags: typescript, vuejs2, vuex

I have a Vue2 Typescript project and I'd like to use `vue-property-decorator`'s `@Watch` on a property in a submodule of my store to react to mutations.  What's the correct approach for this?  Is it sufficient to use dotted notation (not working, but I've tried `@Watch('this.$store.state.myModule.myProperty')` - maybe I got the syntax wrong?), or do I need a separate computed function, or explicit store-level watcher?

Worth mentioning: an `@Watch` on top-level store properties seems to work, and I get an error if I try to `@Watch` via a store getter, i.e. `@Watch(this.$store.getters['myModule/property'])`.

Answer (score 0):

(Amazing what a good night's sleep can do...)

So the trick is to not watch the property directly, but instead bring it in as a computed property via the `mapState` helper:

```
@Component({
    computed: {
        ...mapState<ModuleType>("MyModule", {
            myProperty: (state: ModuleType) => state.myProperty
        })
    }
})
```

and *then* I can watch it:

```
@Watch('myProperty')
myMethod(value: MyPropertyType) {
    // ... do stuff
}
```